# What is the cause for "The namespace on the "definitions" element, is not a valid SOAP version"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am using Apache CXF 2.7.6 version.

> Consuming a service results in this-
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault:
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", the namespace on the "definitions"
>   element, is not a valid SOAP version.     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.readVersion(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:811)...

The inbound message seen in the server logs as constructed by `Apache CXF` works fine if I test it SOAPUI tool.

```
<jaxws:client id="client"
        serviceClass=" service class name"
        address="wsdl address without the ? wsdl" username=" user name"
        password="${password}">
        <jaxws:binding>
            <soap:soapBinding version="1.2"/>
        </jaxws:binding>
        <jaxws:features>
            <beans:bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: did u resolve this issue?
if so could u please help me with the reason. Im facing this issue now